# What is the most robust way to determine the current codepage from a shell script?

Tags: c, bash, unix, shell, codepages

I'd like to determine the environment's current codepage at runtime from a Unix shell script. What's the most reliable way of doing this?

I'm looking into parsing environment variable $LC_ALL, but it isn't always set to a useful value, and its format seems to vary (can be <*locale*>, or <*locale*>.<*code page*>, or <*locale*>.<*code page*>@<*modifier*> etc...).

Is there a better way? I'm essentially after a shell equivalent of what I'd get if I called  nl_langinfo(CODESET) from C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
locale charmap
```